# Trying to run an Update query but error in the syntax

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to create an update query:

`v_sqlcommand = "UPDATE User SET User.Doctor = " & txt_doctor.Text & ", User.DoctorSurgeryAddressStreet = " & txt_streetname.Text & " WHERE User.UserID = " & UserID`

but I keep getting a syntax error thrown at me. I have put in a breakpoint and ran the query  from the debugger and it works when I run the query in access. I have checked the text box names and they are fine. Just a bit puzzled...

Comment: The .Text property is only available on an Access form when the contrl has focus, the default property is .Value so txt_doctor is equivalent to txt_doctor.value. You would be better off using parameters.

Comment: I have had no experience with parameters before, do you know of any good user guides or suggestions as to how this could be done VB 2010

Comment: Are you using vb.net or VBA? VBA is within MS Access.

Comment: I am using VBA. I'm trying to write it to MS Access

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, I assume the values of `Doctor`, `DoctorSurgeryAddressStreet` are Text type, so you need to enclose them in String literals (`'`). Your INSERT should be.

```
v_sqlcommand = "UPDATE User SET User.Doctor = '" & Me.txt_doctor & "', " & _
               "User.DoctorSurgeryAddressStreet = '" & Me.txt_streetname & "' " & _
               "WHERE User.UserID = " & Me.UserID
```

You do not (should not) be using .Text, as this will require the control to have focus before accessing them.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using VB 2010, does this still apply as I am getting Operator & is not defined and the ME.UserID is not  amember of the form.

Comment: @LauraVipond From the menu bar in the VBA editor choose `Tools > References...` and see if any of the selected items are marked as "MISSING".

Comment: Also check the name of UserId, where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 0):

Much confusion here as you stated you use VS2010 while tag VBA was applied. This has been replaced with tag vb.net.
Thus:

```
v_sqlcommand = "UPDATE User SET User.Doctor = '" + Me.txt_doctor.Text + "', " + _
               "User.DoctorSurgeryAddressStreet = '" + Me.txt_streetname.Text + "' " + _
               "WHERE User.UserID = " + Me.UserID.Text + ""
```

Comment: Laura stated quite clearly in her comment that she is using VBA. The VB.Net tag was not added by her.

Comment: Clearly? Laura states she uses VB2010 (VB.NET of VS2010?) which not is VBA. This also matches the original code and the use of property Text to fetch the values of the controls, and that "operator &" is not found.

Comment: To quote her comment "I am using VBA. I'm trying to write it to MS Access –  Laura Vipond 2 days ago" Using the text property is a common VBA error.